# How to generate a CSR for a Meteor App

Tags: ssl, meteor, openssl, csr

I would ideally want it to work on my the server on my laptop, as well as the website I deploy to. The reason being so I can send push notifications to the iOS app.

The certificate depends on the web server, correct? So what kind of webserver is meteor?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.